# Finding probability, expected value, and standard deviation from a sample of a collection of items

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

**Worker A at Assembly Line I made 15 voltage regulators today and 2 of them are defective. Worker B at Assembly Line II made 20 voltage regulators today and 4 of them are defective. Keep in mind that sampling for quality inspect is without replacement.**

**a) An inspector randomly samples 3 voltage regulars from Worker A's products and 4 voltage regulators from Worker B's products. Find the probability that he will find more defectives from Worker A's products than from Worker B's products.**

**b) All voltage regulators made by Worker A and Worker B are mixed. 8 regulators will be randomly sampled from the entire collection. Among sampled regulators, each regulator made by Worker A receives 4 tokens and each regulator made by Worker B receives 3 tokens. Find the expected value and standard deviations for the total number of tokens.**

*What I have tried so far:*

a) The way I understand this part is by letting Y = # of defectives from Worker A, and X = # of defectives from Worker B. So it's asking P(Y > X). I started by trying to do this by brute force and just manually computing all possibilities, since the number of possibilities seems small. For example, I started with:

$P(X \le 2 | Y = 3) +  P(X \le 1 | Y = 2) + P(X \le 0 | Y = 1)$

The issue then became how I can actually compute this. I wasn't sure if I was even supposed to set this up using conditional probability.

b) For the expected value, using the same notation I created in part a, it seemed to be asking for:

$E(4Y + 3X) = 4E(Y) + 3E(X)$

Though at this point I'm getting stuck computing the expected value for this problem. I haven't got to work on standard deviation either, since I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The straightforward way to get the probability is to sum over all possible pairs of $x$ and $y$ :
$$
p=\sum_{x>y}P(X=x)\times P(Y=y).
$$
Notice that the possibilities are actually limited :
$$
p=P(X=1)\times P(Y=0)+
P(X=2)\times P(Y=0)+
P(X=2)\times P(Y=1).
$$
The probabilities $P(X=x)$ and $P(Y=y)$ are hypergeometric :
$$
P(X=x)=\frac{{2\choose x}{13\choose 3-x}}{{15\choose 3}}\quad 0\leq x\leq 2
$$
and
$$
P(Y=y)=\frac{{4\choose y}{16\choose 4-y}}{{20\choose 4}}\quad 0\leq y\leq 4.
$$
Numerically you get 
$$
p=12/35\times 364/969
+ 1/35\times 364/969
+ 1/35\times 448/969=148/969\approx 0.1527.
$$

b) You sample 8 items from a population with 15 As and 20 Bs. The number $T$ of tokens will be 4 As + 3 Bs, that is, 3 + number of As. The number $A$ of As also has an hypergeometric distribution with parameters $n=8$, $r=15$ and $N=35$.

$$
E(T)=3+E(A)=3+8\times 15/35\approx 6.43
\qquad
\sigma_T=\sigma_A=\sqrt{n\,{r\over N}\,({1-{r\over N}})\, {N-n\over N-1}}
\approx 1.247.
$$

Comment: Alright, that makes a lot more sense. I just realized from your comment that X can't be 3 since there were only 2 defectives to begin with. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: For part b, it's 3 + E(B), not 3E(B)? And do we not include 4 + E(A) [or  4E(A)]?

Comment: @Doadle Sorry I missread the problem. You get 3 tokens either way, and one more if it is A. Thus, 4A+3B=3+A. Will edit answer.